# How do you measure a distance along the Z axis in Altium?

Tags: measurement, altium, 3d

If you hit CTRL+M, it's easy to take a measurement along the x or y axis. If you want to measure along the Z axis (for instance, the height of a 3D body), how do you do it?

I googled "measure the along the Z axis altium", "measure standoff height altium", and did the same searches here. No luck.

Thank you in advance for anyone who can help this altium beginner.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to export the .step file, and use other 3D tools, such as Solidworks.

Answer (score 5):

Press '3' to enter 3D view mode.
Tools->3D Body Placement->Measure

You are then prompted to select your points (message appears at the bottom of the screen in the bar with x/y coordinates).

You can measure points on the same object or between two different objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Altium doc page on the feature.  ...it's not very easy to use and only operates on one 3D body, not from one 3D body to another:
http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/PCB_Cmd-SnapSTEPModel_PLPCB~MeasureSTEPSnapDistances((Measure+STEPSnap+Distances))_AD

Personally, I think Altium should look at ditching their 3D working environment and license or co-op a subset of SpaceClaim's 3D engine and UI, of SketchUp's UI.  Both are much faster to get around in for simple operations that most users want to do with 3D.  ...the other 3D CAD UI's are slow and less intuitive for new users.